# *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]

Tags: ios

I am using tableview apple's lazy loading code in my project,but having exception in project. And error is - `*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]`,here is my code please help.But it is working in other project.I have no delegate method.

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LazyTableCell";
    static NSString *PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell";

    NSUInteger nodeCount = [self.entries count];

if (nodeCount == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Loading…";

    return cell;
    }

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (nodeCount > 0)
{
     AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     cell.textLabel.text = appRecord.name;


    if (!appRecord.appIcon)
    {
        if (self.mytable_view.dragging == NO && self.mytable_view.decelerating == NO)
        {
            [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = appRecord.appIcon;
    }

}

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is returning a `nil` value and then `configureCellForDisplay` is expecting a `UITableViewCell`. The storyboard or `XIB` does not have a cell defined with the cell identifier you specified. Better check the spelling of identifier.

Answer (score 14):

Please check for Delegate.

Have you added both delegate or not?

`UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`

```
import UIKit

class UserFriendVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource 
{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you should add cellIdentifier from "Show the attributes inspector". Please fallow just like below snippet.

Firstly added below code to your`-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delagate method.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    ResultCustomTableViewCell *cell = (ResultCustomTableViewCell *)[resultTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ResultTableViewCellIdentifier"];

...
//set the cell property

...
return cell;
}
```

and then jump the "Show the attributes inspector",  While selected cell root view.

[image]

And then paste the same identifier name to identifier section in "Show the attributes inspector". in this case i use this ResultTableViewCellIdentifier.

And one more think. if you use custom cell just like this scenario, you must add below delegate metod. Because your custom cell height can be higher or smaller original tableview height. And Also you should register this nib in viewDidLoad.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [resultTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ResultCustomTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:[ResultCustomTableViewCell reuseIdentifier]];

    }


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

                CGFloat height = 0.0;

                if (tableView == resultTableView){
                    height = 44.0f;
                }

                return height;
            }
```

i hope, it'll fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

`CellIdentifier` I bet your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is returning nil.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LazyTableCell";
    static NSString *PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell";

    NSUInteger nodeCount = [self.entries count];
    if (nodeCount == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier] autorelease];

        }
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Loading…";

        return cell;

    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if (nodeCount > 0) {

        AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = appRecord.name;


        if (!appRecord.appIcon)
        {
            if (self.mytable_view.dragging == NO && self.mytable_view.decelerating == NO)
            {
                [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
            }

            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView.image = appRecord.appIcon;
        }

    }

    return cell;

}
```

That's probably why `[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]` is failing... because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is returning a null value and then `configureCellForDisplay` is expecting a `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 1):

Register your cell in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` method using

```
 [self.tableView registerClass:UITableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Your Reuse Identifier"];
```

if your are using storyboards and use this if you are using a custom cell.

```
[self.tableView registerNib:UINib nibWithNibName:@"Your File Name.xib" bundle:nil forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Your Reuse Identifier"]
```