# UITableViewCell subclass or Prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My question may be stupid, but, I am just curious to know the better approach. When a same complex cell is to be used in many `tableViews`, it is better to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass.

But, if want to go with Prototype cells, by just copy pasting the cell in `tableViews`, will there be difference? Will there be any impact on memory consumption?

Comment: if you want to create only once, and used many times. You should use custom table cell view. i think. When you use dequecellIdentifier, performence will be same. You can look this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/42432992/1514066

Answer (score 2):

Create separate class + xib file (for instance `MyCellUITableViewCell`). Move all your complex UI/Logic to that cell. Then you can reuse this cell every where. Just register nib to `tableView`

For instance:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCellUITableViewCell", bundle: nil)
self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCellUITableViewCell")
```

That way, you can reuse cell on multiple places and won't have to copy it on multiple places.

If you copy your cell, it won't take more memory but app will be heavier. After all, that way you could keep it DRY ( don't repeat yourself).

I missed objective-c flag and wrote in Swift 3 - for Objective-c:

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCellUITableViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellUITableViewCell"];
```